# Best means to poll an Oracle table based on an asynchronous response

Tags: sql, oracle, asynchronous, plsql, oracle12c

How can I handle an asynchronous response that eventually updates a status flag in an Oracle table?

I basically have a PL/SQL routine that make a REST call using `APEX_WEB_SERVICE` API.

My question is, asynchronously, this will eventually update a status flag within a table, which will tell me whether the operation was OK or FAIL.

What is the best way to poll this table to check if a response of OK or FAIL has been returned using Oracle PL/SQL?

I was looking at `DBMS_LOCK.sleep(`) but unsure if this is the best approach. Could DBMS_ALERT also work for this?

Comment: Are you attempting to complete some other action or process as a result, like sending an e-mail or running another procedure?

Comment: @pmdba I need to run another procedure using the results returned from the asynchronous process, assuming it was a staus of OK.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than poll the table at an interval, I would recommend using Oracle Advanced Queues along with Oracle Scheduler. AQ is designed exactly for this sort of thing. You can create a "scheduled" job that is triggered by a message (sent by the asynchronous process at the same time it updates the table) being sent to the queue. Scheduler sees the message and runs the appropriate job or job chain to finish the processing.

See here for a basic example: https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2017/08/21/aq-basics/